# Troubleshooting "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error while trying to prevent POST refresh double-submissions

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to prevent a form from being submitted multiple times when the user refreshes the page.  Here's my code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">

                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Kategori</p></td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td>
                            <select name="kategori">
                            <?php
                            $query = "SELECT id, title FROM forum_kategorier";
                            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                            while(list($id, $title) = $result->fetch_row())
                            {
                                echo "<option value=\"$id\">$title</option>";  
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Title</p></td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <textarea name="tekst_indhold" style="width:716px; height:170px;"></textarea><br />
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="return_page">
                <input type="submit" value="Opret indhold" name="godkendt">
            </form>
            <?php
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `forum_traede` (`kategori_id`, `bruger_id`, `tekst`, `dato`, `titel`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)')) { 
                $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $katgori_id, $bruger_id, $tekst, $titel);
                $katgori_id = $_POST["kategori"];
                $bruger_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
                $tekst = $_POST["tekst_indhold"];
                $titel = $_POST["title"];

                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                if (isset($_POST['return_page'])) {
                    $return_page = $_POST["return_page"];
                } else {
                    header('Location: http://xxxx.dk/bruger-forum-opret/');
                }

            } else {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
        ?>
```

After submitting the form, I get the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/xxx.php:27) in /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/xxx.php on line 78

This appears at the top of the page.

I've also tried moving the form processing code into a separate .php file, but then I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/bruger_forum-indhold-godkendt.php on line 2

How can I redirect the browser to a new page after the form is submitted?

Comment: can some norwegian person edit this text? :)

Comment: ha, i edited out a random f-bomb in there too

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not good at English

Comment: Phoenix, that is an awesome edit. Wish I could upvote you for that alone.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: put all of your PHP code before all of your HTML code.

Comment: Add an `exit();` after you set `location` header.

Comment: @user1433667 we're not on Twitter, use the `@` to notify someone

Answer (score 0):

To address your second problem first:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/bruger_forum-indhold-godkendt.php on line 2

It seems that there is more code in your script than what you posted; there are several references to a `$mysqli` variable whose initialization we do not see in your question.

If you move only the form-processing code into a separate file, but you do not include the code that defines the `$mysqli` variable, you will run into the error noted above:  You are trying to call `$mysqli->prepare()`, but `$mysqli` hasn't been defined yet.

---

Now for the first problem:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/xxx.php:27) in /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/xxx.php on line 78

There are a couple of issues that are contributing to the problem.  We'll tackle them one-at-at-time.

#### 1. The form processing code executes even when the form hasn't been submitted.

At a minimum, you should be checking to make sure the form has been submitted before you start to process it.  Consider something like the following:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  ...
</form>

<?php
  /* Check if the form was submitted. */
  if( $_POST ) {
    /* @todo Validate incoming values. */

    /* If all values are valid, insert into the database. */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `forum_traede` (`kategori_id`, `bruger_id`, `tekst`, `dato`, `titel`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)')) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
```

#### 2. The form HTML is output even if the form has already been submitted.

Similarly, your script should only be outputting the form HTML if the form has not been submitted yet.  This is what is preventing your script from redirecting the browser correctly.

The HTTP response that your script is sending back to the browser comes in two parts:  headers and body.  The header must be sent first, which means that as soon as your script outputs something, PHP will send whatever headers it has at that point to the browser so that it can send the body.

Since your script attempts to output the form HTML before it sets the `location` header, this will make it impossible to do the redirect (by the time PHP evaluates the `header()` statement in your code, the HTTP headers will have already been sent to the browser).

To fix this, you will want to move your form processing code to the top of your script:

```
<?php
  /* Check if the form was submitted. */
  if( $_POST ) {
    /* @todo Validate incoming values. */

    /* If all values are valid, insert into the database. */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `forum_traede` (`kategori_id`, `bruger_id`, `tekst`, `dato`, `titel`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)')) {
      ...
      $stmt->close();

      $return_page = (
        isset($_POST['return_page'])
          ? $_POST['return_page']
          : 'http://xxxx.dk/bruger-forum-opret/'
      );

      header(sprintf('Location: %s', $return_page));
      exit;
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
?>

<!-- If we get to this point, either the form has not been submitted yet,
      or there is an error, so we should display the form HTML.
  -->
<form action="#" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

Note also that I added an `exit;` after the `header()` call.  Since the browser is redirected to a new URL, there is no point in displaying the form anymore.

Also, I was a little unclear as to the purpose of the `$return_page` variable.  I think the intent is to specify in the form the URL that the browser will be redirected to once the form has been processed.  I updated the code in my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I do not understand quite how you want them to build it up? hmm I'm a little unsure about it.

Comment: or you can make it another way. it just has to be such that it can not be sent back then it was written into the fields or imitate. so I'm sure the fashion to get spam in my database ..